# scroll-up effect with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In https://react.dev/community#stack-overflow
originally you see
[image]

When you Scroll up, you see
[image]

How to achieve such effect using material UI (i.e., is there an existing component that support this?)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by tweaking `elevation` property of the `<Appbar/>` component. You can use [useScrollTrigger](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#elevate-app-bar) hook from MUI to trigger elevation. Here is an [example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#elevate-app-bar) on official MUI website.

Implementation will be like this:

```
import useScrollTrigger from '@mui/material/useScrollTrigger'
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar'

//return true when scroll down and when it's true, we show the elevation on the appbar
const triggerElevation = useScrollTrigger({
  disableHysteresis: true,
  threshold: 0,
})

<AppBar elevation={triggerElevation ? 2 : 0}>
    <YourChildComonents/>
</AppBar>
```

I hope it helps!